# ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed

Tags: python, python-3.x

El paquete de Python llamado *Patsy*, ayuda a definir una fórmula con variable dependiente e independiente. La variable que se define a la izquierda de `'~'` es la variable dependiente, y las variables que se definen a la derecha de la misma son las variables independientes. Las variables encerradas dentro de C () son tratadas como variables categóricas.
Del DataFrame `"titanic_3.csv"`, necesito crear dos conjuntos: set de  entrenamiento y set de pruebas. Este DataFrame se encuentra accesible en la carpeta Ficheros de **[este enlace](https://github.com/akitxu/Aprendiendo-GitHub)**

Al ejecutar el script

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from patsy import dmatrices
# Change directory 
os.chdir("G:\Py_machine_learning\Ficheros")
df = pd.read_csv("titanic_3.csv")
# Aplicar axis as 1 para eliminar las columnas con las siguientes etiquetas
df = df.drop(["ticket","cabin","name", "Unnamed: 14", "Unnamed: 15", "Unnamed: 16",
              "Unnamed: 17", "Unnamed: 18", "Unnamed: 19"], axis=1)
# Eliminamos valores Na
df = df.dropna()
from patsy import dmatrices
formula = "survived ~ C(pclass) + C(sex) + age + sibsp + C(embarked) + parch" 
# Crea un diccionario de resultados para mantener nuestros resultados de regresión 
# para un fácil análisis posterior
df_train = df.iloc[ 0: 600, : ]
df_test = df.iloc[ 600: , : ]
# Divide los datos en variables dependientes e independientes.
# Crea los conjuntos de datos de entrenamiento y prueba
y_train,x_train = dmatrices(formula, data=df_train, return_type = 'dataframe')
y_test,x_test = dmatrices(formula, data=df_test,  return_type = 'dataframe')
```

me devuelve el error:

> ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
>   ¿Cuál es la causa de este error?.

Comment: Efectivamente, el df descargado de Kaggle no era el completo. Si os parece que no aporta nada a otras personas, podemos eliminarla

Comment: Pueden poner el comentario como respuesta y aceptarlo, así otros sabrán qué revisar cuando encuentren este error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras hacer el `df.dropna()` el dataframe resultante sólo tiene 142 filas en este ejemplo, por lo que al tratar de seleccionar de la fila 600 en adelante para `df_test` terminas con un dataframe vacío, y de ahí el error.

Es cierto que el mensaje no es intuitivo, al mencionar una dimensión negativa que no se ve en tu código, pero esto ocurre porque internamente el patsy intenta crear una matriz unidad (unos en la diagonal y ceros fuera) de dimensiones `len(levels)-1`, llamando a `np.eye()`, y ya que `levels` es cero en este caso, acaba causando una dimensión negativa que causa la excepción en `np.eye()`.